# Node.js https server throws 'bad decrypt' error if cert passphrase has $ in it

Tags: node.js, express, https, server

Any other special char in the passphrase works but not when passphrase has $ in it for some reason, for example passphrase like `te$t`, the error thrown while starting the server is -

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Error (native)
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:106:19)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:598:25)
    at new Server (https.js:36:14)
    at Object.exports.createServer (https.js:56:10)
```

Here is how the code looks like -

```
  const sslConfig = {
    secureOptions: ...,
    cert: fileSystem.readFileSync(<cert path>),
    key: fileSystem.readFileSync(<key path>),
    ciphers: [ ... ].join(':'),
  };

  if (<has passphrase setup>) {
    sslConfig.passphrase = fileSystem.readFileSync(<passphrase path>, { encoding: 'utf8' }),
    // console logging the passphrase here shows the correct passphrase
    // file path for passphrase file is valid
  }

  const expressApp = express(); // followed by settings specific to express.js

  https.createServer(sslConfig, expressApp).listen(...);
```

FYI - this is using Node.js v0.12.7, its a legacy app. Upgrading node version is not an option at the moment.

Any pointers?

Comment: With your cut pathes no way to help. Try to escape the `$` with a backslash

Comment: @Marc, I did try that, didnt help unfortunately

Comment: Linux or Windows OS? Can you provide a example with paths? Have you tried it with "hardcoded" passphrase for a test?

Comment: @Marc its on FreeBSD 8.4, the paths are pretty straight forward just like regular paths and since I am able to console.log it after fetching content of those files, I know that its being fetched correctly. I also tried hardcoding the exact passphrase from the file into the config but that didnt work either.

Comment: Why not just change the passhprase or remove it complete? If some one have access to your private key you have a fundamental other problem...

Comment: @Marc I agree, that is a workaround but not sure what the root cause is for this issue since any other special char works fine.

Comment: The only think that comes to my mind is that on unix/linux os `$` is a special char in the termnal. That and the very old node version in conjunction may produce the error above. But thats just a speculation.